# How to change the name of windows app in flutter?

Tags: windows, flutter, dart, appicon

Question No 1:
I am developing a windows app during this I have to change the name "admin_panel" to "Admin Panel"
And in Runner.rc file I have changed the OriginalFilename to "Admin Panel.exe" but it shows admin_panel at the top.
[image]

Question No 2:
And also I will be grateful towards you if you also provide the information regarding app icon. I was trying to use png file but it's not working. It needs ico file. I also tried to change the extension of image from png to ico but it still not working. So, how can I change that png file into desktop app icon.

Answer (score 1):

Navigate to the `..windows/runner` folder within your project directory, as shown below:

[image: image1]

Open up the `main.cpp` file and scroll down until you find the last conditional, like so:

[image: image2]

You can see from my current project that I've got a string saying "IMS Workbench". This is my desired window name (yours will say "admin_panel"). Change this to "Admin Panel" to apply your desired name.

**Note:**

It would make sense for there to be a single solution to accommodate multiple operating systems. I've not yet looked for one, but I will update this answer when I find it.

Answer (score 0):

Try changing ProductName

"ProductName","Admin Panel"

To change the icon you just need to replace the icon file in your project:

Windows: windows/runner/resources/app_icon.ico
macOS: macos/Runner/Assets.xcassets/AppIcon.appiconset

if still not updated the icon try flutter clean